# does its matter how i write my SQL query(if its correct)

Tags: sql, select

hi guys i just wrote 2 queries that gave me the same result i wanted to ask you if it is important how i write it :

1)

```
select First_Name, monthly_discount, pack_id, main_phone_num
from customers
where pack_id  in(select p.pack_id
from packages p JOIN sectors s
on s.sector_id = p.sector_id where s.sector_name = 'business')
```

2)

```
SELECT first_name , monthly_discount , pack_id , main_phone_num ,
                    secondary_phone_num
FROM customers
WHERE pack_id IN
            (SELECT pack_id
                FROM packages
                WHERE sector_id IN
                        (   SELECT sector_id
                            FROM sectors
                            WHERE sector_name = 'Business'))
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using. I would probably go with `EXISTS/JOIN` combination

Answer (score 2):

Is it important how your write it?

Yes.  First, just because two queries returning the same result set on your data does not mean that they logically do the same thing.  For instance `select 2*2` and `select 1 + 3` return the same value, but they are not doing the same calculation.  The same is very true of SQL queries.

In your case, the queries *are* identical.  For any set of data they will return the same result set.

Second, even when queries are functionally identical, databases can implement the versions differently.  This usually takes the form of different underlying algorithms (you might be surprised at how many ways there are to do a `join`).  This would probably apply in your cases, because `in` and `join` often have different algorithms.

The third point is probably the most important.  Queries should be written so *humans* can read them, understand them, and maintain them.  Most people find nested `in`s a bit difficult to follow (and nested `not in`s are pretty incomprehensible to mere mortals).  On the other hand, `join`s are more general and need to be understood to use SQL effectively.

Your primary consideration should be whether the query really does what you want.  A very close second is readability, clarity, and maintainability.

Comment: thank you very much helped me a lot in understanding sql a litle bit more

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries provides you same result, but in 
case of SQL you will get an perfomance issues.
Using WHERE clause increases your execution time compared 
to JOINS. In the first query you have use JOIN and WHERE clause
which fetches you the result fasetr compared to second query. Using 
JOINS every where rather than WHERE condition in the first query fetches you data more faster 
than both the queries as provided below,

```
SELECT C.First_Name, C.monthly_discount, C.pack_id, C.main_phone_num 
    FROM customers C
    INNER JOIN packages P
    ON P.pack_id  = C.pack_id  
    INNER JOIN sectors S
    ON S.sector_id = P.sector_id
AND S.sector_name = 'business'
```

Comment: This is *not* equivalent to the two queries in the question. (it can result in the same customer being selected more than once) And the idea that the "condition in the where clause" is costly is complete nonsense, IMHO.